# What width should my images be to be neat on my app?

Tags: java, android, image, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view on my android app main page that displays a list of pictures and I can't decide which width to give my images so that they are not too heavy but still very neat. (My images take the whole width of the screen.)

I know every Android device has a different format but I need a one-size-fits-all.

I currently have images on my res folder with width 500px (and approx. 350px height). The images weight between 30ko and 100ko. But I must admit they are not very neat ...

So I guess I have to pack pictures with a greater width to gain quality, but I have no idea how much.

How does Instagram does it ? Pictures are always very neat, how do they do this ? What are the characteristics of their pictures ? I guess they weight a ton, no ? (like 500ko per image ?) or am I wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use this site as your ***last resource***, after doing your Research and Development task. Google keywords: `android supporting multiple screens`.

Comment: `I need a one-size-fits-all.` Then provide only the **highest resolution** ones (say, the ones for the **drawables-xxxhdpi** bucket). So that they will be scaled **down** (which is way better than the other direction). This way, the pixels will be ***blended*** instead of being ***stretched***

Comment: I have actually read this on the documentation but I thought there would be other more "practical" solutions like : "usually images with 1000px wide are the most suitable" - If I follow your advice, my apk size (or my download times) will skyrocket ... what do you do usually ?

Comment: I provide ALL the required images, for ALL the buckets. This said, I use the **LEAST AMOUNT** of images which are absolutely needed (mostly **9 patches**). For the rest, I use SVGs (**vectors**), fonts (**vectors**) and drawables (**vectors**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite some time testing on different sizes and weights, my conclusion is that 500px wide images are not displayed very well on devices in general when you want to have image that take the whole width of the phone. But you can have light images (between 30Ko and 80Ko).

Below 500px width is not a good idea.

When you go up to 1000px wide images, you get a whole better quality, that gives your app a better look and feel in my opinion. But obviously images are somewhat bigger (between 80 and 190Ko)

When you go up to 1500px wide images, you have to be careful to the weight of the image. I wouldn't recommand having images that weight more than 200 Ko. But at least you got very good quality ... which is something nice :D

I hope that could help

Answer (score 0):

There are utilities ('Image Optimizers') that shrink jpeg images without any significant quality loss, you can find some of them on Google for manual use.

When showing a lot of images, you can use a library such as [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) to do this for you. I believe that apps such as Instagram might have their own code but same same. The file sizes are usually 15-300 kb, depending on the 'complexity' of the image.

Comment: Thank you Neria for that answer, but I guess I don't want my images to be processed in the app. I want them to be packaged directly to the best suitable width (currently 500px width). Thank you for that 300kb upper boundary, it gives me an idea about how high I can go